# CSS margin-left applied to incorrect class heading

Tags: html, css

For some unknown reason when I add margin-left to .basic-info h1, it also applies to h1 in .bottomContent. Therefore h1 in bottomContent is also give a margin left of 80px. Meaning when I do .bottomContent h1{ padding-left:80px}, this in theory should be the only one applied but it's not, so the padding-left is doubeld on h1 in bottomContent.

As an easy solution I could just remove bottomContent h1, and leave the CSS as it is with .basic-info but clearly i'm doing something wrong.

HTML

```
div class = "basic-info">
    <div class ="image"> <img src = "logo.jpg" alt = "this is an image"> </div>
    <div class = "inside-info">
        <h1> Know better. Book better. Go better. </h1>

        <p>See the latest reviews and compare the lowest hotel prices from 200+ hotel booking sites to help you make the most of your trip
        See the latest reviews and compare the lowest hotel prices from 200+ hotel booking sites to help you make the most of your trip
        See the latest reviews and compare the lowest hotel prices from 200+ hotel booking sites to help you make the most of your trip
        See the latest reviews and compare the lowest hotel prices from 200+ hotel booking sites to help you make the most of your trip
        See the latest reviews and compare the lowest hotel prices from 200+ hotel booking sites to help you make the most of your trip</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "bottomContent">
        <h1> Top hotels: Recommendations </h1>
        <div class ="number-one">
            <img src = "smallimages.jpg" alt = "this is an image ">
            <img src = "smallimages.jpg" alt = "this is an image ">
            <img src = "smallimages.jpg" alt = "this is an image ">

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.basic-info p,h1{
    margin-left:80px;
    width:50%;
}

.bottomContent h1{
        margin-left:80px;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `margin-left: 80px` is being applied to both `.basic-info p` and `h1` since you have a comma in there. You need to do something like this for it to work...

```
.basic-info p, .basic-info h1 {
    margin-left:80px;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to give margin left to .inside-info h1 not .bottomContent h1
so u can give css like..
`.basic-info .inside-info h1{
      margin-left:80px;
}`

this is not apply on h1 in bottomContent.